# Extracting values from YAML into Jinja template for Ansible playbook

Tags: jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have a YAML file with content as like below:

```
cat ../../ansible/playbooks/vars/patching-config.yml
---
patching_tag_name: "Patching"
my_windows_patching:
  - {
      OS: "WINDOWS",
      tag_value: "myProdA",
      frequency: "Month", #patching frequency. OneTime|Day|Hour|Week|Month|Minute
      interval: 1, #interval of the schedule.
      rebootSetting: "never", #ifRequired|never|always
      PatchGroup: testA,
      startDate: "2020-01-16T23:59:59Z",
      expiryDate: "2020-02-16T23:59:59Z",
      duration: "PT2H0M",
      timeZone: "Australia/Sydney",
      updateClassifications: "Critical,Important,Moderate" 
    }
```

I want to extract the values of **updateClassifications** from above **YML** file in Jinja Template file **MaintenanceWindow.yml.j2**

```
Resources:
  WindowsNonProdBaseline:
    Type: AWS::SSM::PatchBaseline
    Properties:
      Name: Windows-Non-Prod-Baseline
      Description: Baseline containing all updates approved for Windows instances
      OperatingSystem: {{ item.OS }}
      PatchGroups:
      - {{ item.PatchGroup }}
      ApprovalRules:
        PatchRules:
        - PatchFilterGroup:
            PatchFilters:
            - Values:
              # - Critical
              # - Important
              # - Moderate
              {% for item in item.updateClassifications %}
                - {{ item }}
              {% endfor %}
```

I'm trying with the code described above, below one more time snippet:

```
              {% for item in item.updateClassifications %}
                - {{ item }}
              {% endfor %}
```

I'm calling **patching-config.yml** in my **tasks/main.yml** as below

```
- include_vars: "{{playbook_dir}}/vars/patching-config.yml"
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: create a cloudformation stack
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "New-Ansible-cloudformation"
    state: "present"
    disable_rollback: true
    template_body: "{{ lookup('template', '../../cloudformation/patching/MaintenanceWindow.yml.j2') }}"
  with_items: "{{ telstra_windows_patching }}"
```

Finally, invoking role as below

```
cat ansible/playbooks/patching.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - patching-cf-ssm
```

Unfortunately, it is not working.

Any lead shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are you passing as items to your jinja2 template? Paste your ansible template task in your question here to better understand the input to jinja2 template

Comment: I have updated the question with tasks/main.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

Your task is using telstra_windows_patching in with_items where as your variable file has variable name as my_windows_patching.

Assuming you are using the same name say my_windows_patching in your task and var file, if you are trying to save json object in yaml variable my_windows_patching you don't need - before curly braces. You can define something like this

```
my_windows_patching:
   {
      OS: "WINDOWS",
      tag_value: "myProdA",
      frequency: "Month", #patching frequency. OneTime|Day|Hour|Week|Month|Minute
      interval: 1, #interval of the schedule.
      rebootSetting: "never", #ifRequired|never|always
      PatchGroup: testA,
      startDate: "2020-01-16T23:59:59Z",
      expiryDate: "2020-02-16T23:59:59Z",
      duration: "PT2H0M",
      timeZone: "Australia/Sydney",
      updateClassifications: "Critical,Important,Moderate" 
    }
```

If you want to use elements inside my_windows_patching object with dot notation directly you could change the variable from object to a list something like,

```
my_windows_patching:
    -  OS: "WINDOWS"
       tag_value: "myProdA"
```

Comment: Actually, this shall not work. the issue was in the patching-config.yml file. I shall post the file which worked for me. Thanks appreciate your input.

Comment: I've updated my answer if you want to access individual elements of the my_windows_patching with a dot notation.